# How to I run a PyCharm project as it was in a previous commit?

Tags: git, pycharm

I was working on building page X of my web app and did a few commits. Let's say:

```
Commit 11
Commit 10
Commit 9
```

Later, when I visited page Y of the app, I noticed some text had changed position. Apparently, the changes on page X during the commits 9-11 affected page Y.

Now I want to be able to run the project as it was in Commit 8 (so, before I added the new feature). But, I don't want to delete Commit 9, 10, and 11. I just want to temporarily check out (is that the right word) Commit 8, run it, and then go back to where I was, which is Commit 11. I am not even sure if this is the thought process to troubleshoot the text alignment issue though.

Comment: `git checkout <commit hash you want to see>`?

Comment: That takes you to a particular commit, without losing the most recent commits, correct? And then I have to use the same command to go back to the most recent commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

It seems I needed a git check-out operation. In PyCharm, that can be done by going to the Git panel, Logs, right-click over the commit whose files you want to temporarily get in your local project, go to Check Out Revision xxxxx.

Then, experiment with that version of the project and then go back through the above steps, but this time doing the checkout on the most recent commit.

Comment: I don't use PyCharm, but in most environments, to get back to the latest commit for branch name X you would run `git checkout X`. The point of a branch name is that it stores the latest commit hash ID for you, so that you don't need to remember or find it. By using the branch name with a checkout command, Git also knows to *update* that name when you make a *new* commit. It's possible that PyCharm hides this entire mechanism with some other mechanism of its own, but that seems unlikely.